# Send emails in a django development environment on OS X leopard

Tags: django, macos, email

Hay, i was wondering how i would go about setting up django so that i can send emails from a standard Leopard installation.

In php i just use mail() and it sends the mail for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/):

> Mail is sent using the SMTP host and port specified in the EMAIL_HOST  and EMAIL_PORT  settings. The EMAIL_HOST_USER  and EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD  settings, if set, are used to authenticate to the SMTP server, and the EMAIL_USE_TLS  setting controls whether a secure connection is used.

So set your `EMAIL_HOST` to a friendly SMTP server which will relay mail for you, and away you go.

Again, from the docs:

```
from django.core.mail import send_mail

send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', 'from@example.com',
    ['to@example.com'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: For example, I usually just use my gmail account:
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'USERNAME'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'PASSWORD'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True

Comment: This ALWAYS replies with an error - 
getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None